# converting multi-number strings array into arrays of floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, numpy

I read some data from a text file and placed them into an array that has the following format:

```
['-1.92784 -1.28125 0.1'...'-1.92784 -1.35417 0.1' '-1.92784 -1.42708 0.1']
```

I want it in the following format:

```
[
 ...
 [-1.92784 -1.35417  0.1    ]
 [-1.92784 -1.42708  0.1    ]
...
]
```

I am not sure how to do this, I keep getting an error saying: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype' when I try to convert it to floats.

I know that loading my file as a csv with pandas does this formatting for me already, but I can't do that because I have other text that I had to parse through and remove to only include the values seen above (I don't believe I can use regex with pandas?)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you can split each element in that string array and then convert the results to float. and you can use regex with pandas

Comment: You mean you have a _list_, not an _array_? There are no arrays in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.fromstring`:

```
l = ['-1.92784 -1.28125 0.1', '-1.92784 -1.35417 0.1', '-1.92784 -1.42708 0.1']
np.array([np.fromstring(i, sep=" ") for i in l])
```

Output:

```
array([[-1.92784, -1.28125,  0.1    ],
       [-1.92784, -1.35417,  0.1    ],
       [-1.92784, -1.42708,  0.1    ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#original array
arr = np.array(['-1.92784 -1.28125 0.1', '-1.92784 -1.35417 0.1', '-1.92784 -1.42708 0.1'])
print (arr)
['-1.92784 -1.28125 0.1' '-1.92784 -1.35417 0.1' '-1.92784 -1.42708 0.1']
```

First split by whitespaces to list of nested lists:

```
L = [x.split() for x in arr]
print (L)
[['-1.92784', '-1.28125', '0.1'], 
 ['-1.92784', '-1.35417', '0.1'], 
 ['-1.92784', '-1.42708', '0.1']]
```

Then convert to 2d array, working if same elements in each sublist:

```
arr1 = np.array(L).astype(float) 
print (arr1)
[[-1.92784 -1.28125  0.1    ]
 [-1.92784 -1.35417  0.1    ]
 [-1.92784 -1.42708  0.1    ]]
```